# How to exclude patterns in list.files() in R?

Tags: r

Excel creates temporary folders with the `~` sign in front of the file when the file is open.

For example, a folder will have:

`Data.xlsx` and `~$Data.xlsx`

How do I exclude any files that begin with `~`?

I've tried `startsWith` as well as `pattern=^(?!~))`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pattern = "^[^~]"`.